# Use LearningTransport with nservicebus azure trigger functions (NServiceBusTriggerFunction)

Tags: azure-functions, nservicebus, azure-triggers

Trying to use the example code snippet:

```
builder.UseNServiceBus(ctx =>
{
    var endpointConfig = new EndpointConfiguration("ConsoleEndpoint");
    endpointConfig.UseTransport(new LearningTransport());

    return endpointConfig;
});
```

It's not working, also tried similar stuff to no avail.

When I run the azure function locally in the functions "emulator", it would be fine for me to use the local file system for the messages (LearningTransport), however the config.UseTransport doesn't accept an Instance of LearningTransport.

What would be the correct way to use the LearningTransport with the azure functions trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NServiceBus support for functions only works with [Service Bus](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/azure-functions-service-bus/) and [Storage Queues](https://docs.particular.net/previews/azure-functions-storage-queues). If you want to run locally, the latter should be working with Azurite.

Worth noting that NServiceBus support for functions is based on the triggers functions provide, not the transports NServiceBus has. Therefore LearningTransport would not be supported as it’s not a valid function trigger.

Comment: yeah, was already curious as how you would watch the file system to trigger the function :D Thanks for clarification, good to know it's not possible, so I don't waste my time trying further